# Open Ajax Issue

Tags: ajax

When I run my ajax file, a problem caused by XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource,true) occurs. It is said that " Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012" ". Does anyone know the solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to access a file on another domain. This is forbidden in AJAX for obvious security reasons.

If the data source is one you control, try using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) in order to circumvent this restriction. Otherwise, you're out of luck for the most part, unless you want use server-side code to route the request through your own server.

Comment: Beside JSONP, is there another way to deal with it?